# The subscription doesn't have permissions to register the resource provider Microsoft.Sql

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm setup up as a contributor to a resource group in azure. I have successfully created a web app and a storage account, but I don't have permission to create a sql server and sql db?

I've been granted the following roles:

- Contributor
- SQL DB Contributor
- SQL Security Manager
- SQL Server Contributor
- Website Contributor

But I still get this error when creating a sql server:

"The subscription Microsoft Azure Enterprise doesn't have permissions to register the resource prover(s): Microsoft.Sql."

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To overcome this error you would need subscription owner rights, or make someone register that provider for you with appropriate rights, or create a custom role and assign that to user(s) that need to register providers.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azure4fun/2016/10/20/common-problem-when-using-azure-resource-groups-rbac/

Comment: "So the bottom line is, we *DO NOT* need to grant access permissions to the subscription level". You do not need subscription contributor rights, but it looks like that subscription is missing the Microsoft.Sql Provider. If you run: 

`get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable |where {$_.Registrationstate -eq "Registered"}` 

you can see that it is missing. To add it, run: 

`Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Sql`.

Comment: well, it depends on how you want to approach that, just like i said, either grant rights and register yourself, or register at subscription level or custom role route

Comment: create a custom role for that or use owner, I've updated the answer

Comment: Having a subscription owner enable the provider is the proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Following the steps in the MS blog referenced in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513241/the-subscription-doesnt-have-permissions-to-register-the-resource-provider-micr/40513394#40513394) under the heading "Preregister all providers in a subscription" worked for me - once I realised that I had to select the correct subscription first.

So the commands that fixed it for me, which I ran in Azure Cloud Shell were:

```
PS Azure:\> Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "<The Subscription Name>"
PS Azure:\> get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable | foreach-object{Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace $_.ProviderNamespace}
```

Comment: +1. This seems to be a more appropriate solution in my cases as well. We can't just hand out "Owners" to everyone.

Comment: This is *highly* discouraged and should not be an acceptable path for anyone and it is not an appropriate solution because it enables *ALL* resource providers. Enabling some resource providers adds apps in Azure Active Directory and you should avoid adding them if you do not need them.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers

Answer (score 1):

There may be related security setting for what you're trying to add but what you need to do is make sure the Resource Provider is registered. You can see a link for this under your subscribers [Take a look at this Azure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIxnW.png)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need subscription contributor rights, but it looks like that subscription is missing the Microsoft.Sql Provider. Using the [Az Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.1.0), if you run:

`get-AzResourceProvider -ListAvailable | where-object {$_.Registrationstate -eq "Registered"}`

You can see that it is missing. To add it, run:

`Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Sql.`

NB: This answer is adapted from Blake Erickson's comment on the answer he accepted to his own question, and is actually the right thing to do here. In contrast to another of the answers, I believe it is better not to register all resource providers as this may not be desired.